# How to take 8 bits of int8 variable and put in the char variable?

Tags: c, type-conversion

I have a function which extract a int8 variable from a pkt.
There is another function which prints the value but it takes input in the form of char.
Now I want to take that int8 variable, convert it in char format while preserving the bits and then input that char variable to the printing function. I am really doubful about the typecasting thing, as it is not giving me correct results as it seems.
Here is the code.

```
void SampleApp_MessageMSGCB( afIncomingMSGPacket_t *pkt )
{

  int8 test_rssi_value = pkt->rssi; // i want to do this & convert int8 to char type which I can input to HalUARTWrite
  unsigned char* Recv_RSSI = (unsigned char*)pkt->rssi; // I don't want to do this
  HalLedBlink  (HAL_LED_4, 4, 50, 250); 
  HalUARTWrite ( HAL_UART_PORT_0, Recv_RSSI, 1 );
}
```

and

```
uint16 HalUARTWrite ( uint8 port, uint8 *pBuffer, uint16 length )
{
--
}
```

Thanks
Also is there any ZStack person who could help me with this:
http://e2e.ti.com/support/wireless_connectivity/f/158/p/355391/1249087.aspx#1249087

Comment: You have a couple of problems with your code: First you get `pkt->rssi` as a plain 8-bit integer, then in the next line you get `pkt->rssi` again, but this time as a pointer. It can't be both things at the same time. If `pkt->rssi` is in fact an 8-bit integer, then if you want to get the address to it you should use the address-of operator `&`, like in `&pkt->rssi`.

Comment: Also note that on almost all modern computers a `char` is 8 bits.

Comment: what if I do this: int8 rssi_value = pkt->rssi; then char* pAdd = &rssi_value; then use HALUartWrite(port,pAdd,1); or this could be more correct. Actually I thought (unsigned char*)pkt-rssi would typecast int8 to char but i think i did do mistake there. Let me try the new thing.

Comment: Why not use `&pkt->rssi` directly in the call? There's no need for intermediate variables.

Comment: Thank you so much :) ! Hopefully it is correct now :). If any issues I will reply.

Comment: What about this: int8 test_rssi_value = pkt->rssi; then uint8* pAddr = &test_rssi_value; then HalUARTWrite ( HAL_UART_PORT_0, pAddr, 1 ); I removed that typecasting thing I guess it isn't required ?

Comment: If your problem is to take out the bits independently from the int8 variable, this code snippet may help you:


    char store[8];
    int abc = pkt->rssi; 
    int count = 0;
    
    while (count<8)
    {
       store[count] = (abc>>count)&0x01;
       count++
    }
finally the store array will have the bits independently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since on most modern platforms `char` is an 8-bit integer, 8-bit types such as `int8_t` are actually based on `char`. The problem is that the signedness of `char` is left for the compiler to decide, so for some compiler converting between e.g. `char` and `uint8_t` is straightforward and for other compilers it's conversion between `char` and `int8_t` that's straight. Because of the signed/unsigned issue you still have to use casting.

Now to solve your problem, you don't actually *need* the intermediate variables, or using `char` in any form. Using the address-of operator (unary `&`) you can simply pass a pointer to `pkt->rssi` directly as an argument to your function:

```
void SampleApp_MessageMSGCB( afIncomingMSGPacket_t *pkt )
{
    HalLedBlink  (HAL_LED_4, 4, 50, 250); 
    HalUARTWrite ( HAL_UART_PORT_0, (uint8 *) &pkt->rssi, 1 );
}
```

If the type of `pkt->rssi` already *is* `uint8` then you don't even have to do the type-casting.